# Laravel 'Data Missing' on save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to save a new record to a Model,

```
$new_employee = new Employee(array('name' => 'xxx','username' => 'yyy','email' => 'zzz','created_at' => $datetime, 'updated_at' => $datetime));
$new_employee->save();
```

I get

```
InvalidArgumentException
Data missing
```

But it isn't pointing to the data that actually missing, how can i check what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the Employee model
Also check the table structure if you have data field, and if it's mandatory
This is usually the case

Also, you [don't need to put updated_at and created_at fields](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps), this is done automatically by eloquent ( except when you have $timestamps=false )

Answer (score 1):

I think your data in `created_at` is wrong.The default format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.You can override `$dateFormat` in `Model`.